# Fill one property of class by selecting one value on dropdownlist of another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class Client that have some properties in particular one is restriction_type. Also, I create another class Restriction with an ID and a name properties. The name property correspond to the restriction_type.

Then I display the name of all restrictions in my database in the dropdown list:

```
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
     @using (Html.BeginForm("AddRestrictions","Restrictions",FormMethod.Get)){
    <p> Type de restriction: 
     @Html.DropDownList("ClientRestr_type", "All")  
    </p>

    <input type="submit"value="Ajouter"/>
}
```

That is my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddRestriction(string ClientRestr_type, Restriction restriction)
{
   var RestrLst = new List<string>();
   var RestrQry = from d in db.Restrictions
                               orderby d.name
                               select d.name;

   RestrLst.AddRange(RestrQry.Distinct());
   ViewBag.ClientRestr_type = new SelectList(RestrLst);
   var clients = from c in db.Restrictions select c;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClientRestr_type))
       return View();

   else
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         // Here I have maybe to find the way to solve my problem
      }
}
```

So I want to add the name property of Restriction in the restriction_type property of my Model Client.

Model Client:

public class Client

```
{
    [Required]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public string compte
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public string portefeuille
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public String restriction_type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public Boolean etat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean decision
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Model Restriction:

public class Restriction

```
{
    public int restrictionID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

What do you think about my GetRestrictions() method

private SelectList GetRestrictions()

{

```
        var RestrLst = new List<string>();
        var RestrQry = from d in db.Restrictions
                       orderby d.name
                       select d.name;

        RestrLst.AddRange(RestrQry.Distinct());

        return new SelectList(RestrLst);

    }
```

But unfortunately I have an error: Impossible to convert System.Web.Mvc.SelectList to MyApp.Models.Client at line:

model.RestrictionList = GetRestrictions();

I don't understand why

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I edit again my post, the problem is at the end or on the title. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I would create a ViewModel containing AND the property where you store the type AND the collection which you will use to fill the dropdown. This will make it easier and will allow you to drop the use of the ViewBag (yuk)

Comment: It not clear what you actually want. Your not even populating your dropdown and you are not posting anything relating to `Restriction`. Please update question to include the Get method in your controller and a few properties of your `Client` class

Comment: Are your trying to create a new `Restriction` or a new `Client`? - your view makes no sense in relation to your action method

Comment: I want to add the restriction_type property of client when the user filling the form with all other properties of Clients. By choosing a restriction in the dropdownlist that shows the names of Restriction. Maybe I don't have to create another model Restriction ?? Thank you

Comment: Do I have to use DropdownListFor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified example:

View model

```
public class ClientVM
{
  public Client Client { get; set; }
  public SelectList RestrictionList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ClientVM model = new ClientVM();
  model.Client = new Client();
  model.RestrictionList = GetRestrictions(); // your code to return the select list
  return View("Edit", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
  ClientVM model = new ClientVM();
  model.Client = // call database to get client based on ID
  model.RestrictionList = GetRestrictions();
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ClientVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.RestrictionList = GetRestrictions();
    return View(model);
  }
  Client client = model.Client;
  // Save and redirect
  ....
}
```

View

```
@model YourNamespace.ClientVM
@using (Html.BeginForm() {
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.ID)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.compte)
  ...
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Client.restriction_type, Model.RestrictionList)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just for the ClientVM do I have to create it in separate folder ViewModels ? Because I have an error on Client when I create a separate folder. Also, do I have to create the RestrictionList property in my model Restriction ?

Comment: I recommend a separate folder for ViewModels (assuming your application is MyApp, then in the view it would be `@model MyApp.ViewModels.ClientVM`). No you do not have to create a RestrictionList property in model Restriction - its a collection that relates to the view only (so you can make a selection and assign it to a property)

Comment: ok but why the object Client is not recognize ? in the ClientViewModel

Comment: Add a using statement to your ViewModel (e.g. using MyApp.Models)

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I have to create a database context for the controller or I just link it to the ClientViewModel ?

Comment: Your view model should not know any thing about your database - its sole responsibility is to pass values to the view. Saving objects to the database is the responsibility of the controller (note the last line of the `[HttpPost] Edit method).

Comment: it is ok, but I am sorry I have an another question about the GetRestrictions(). Do I have to implement it in the class ClientViewModel ? Also I think there is a typo it is model.RestrictionList not .restrictions ? thanks again

Comment: I recommend `GetRestrictions() should be a private method in your controller class. It should not be in your view model as explained above. (and your right about the typo - answer edited).

Comment: I have edited your answer to show you my GetRestrictions() method but I have an error line model.RestrictionList = GetRestrictions();

Comment: error is. impossible to convert type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList to MyApp.Models.Client

Comment: You cant edit my answer. Post a new question with the details of the code and error

Comment: There are 4min last to wait, because there is the rule that I can't answer until 8h after my post..

Comment: I don't know why I can't answer since the 8hours are past, but I think it's ok now I edited my own post

Comment: Check my answer again - look at the definition of class ClientVM - you must have `public Client RestrictionList { get; set; }` instead of `public SelectList RestrictionList { get; set; }`. Any further issues, please post a new question - I wont respond any further on this page.

Comment: But just to finish I don't understand why it should be Client and not SelectList because RestrictionList is a list of Restriction not an object Client ?